# Shortest path animation using RotateAnimation

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to do shortest path rotation animation between two angles. I am using RotateAnimation(fromDegrees, toDegrees, pivotX, pivotY) method to animate the Image.

The problem is that when fromDegrees is 350 and toDegrees is 10, its rotating the complete circle (340 degrees) instead of just 20 degrees clockwise rotation.

Is there a way to force a minimal rotation?

Comment: I noticed similar behaviour when implementing a GPS compass so had a check to see if the needle was moving from between >270 and <360 to between >=0 and <90, or from between <90 and >=0 to between >270 and <360, and set the animation duration to 0 so you wouldn't see the spin going the wrong way. It's a hack but as long as the compass did not rotate wildly, it was barely noticeable.

Did you find a clean solution?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of RotateAnimation you can use [ViewPropertyAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) which has a method [rotationBy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html#rotationBy(float)), that rotates the view **BY** the specified value, so you don't need 'from' and 'to' values.

The main difference between those two Animations is mainly, that a RotateAnimation only moves the pixels on the screen, so for example an OnClickListener will not animate with the pixels, while ViewPropertyAnimator changes the actual property/position of the View on the screen.

ViewPropertyAnimator is also really helpful, because its very easy to implement.
A minimal implementation of ViewPropertyAnimator with a rotation of 20 degrees clockwise would look like this :

```
yourImage.animate().rotationBy(20);
```

It's never wrong to set a duration and it's also recommended to set an Interpolator, because it makes any animation seem more realistic :

```
yourImage.animate()
    .rotationBy(20) -> degrees -20 would be counter clockwise
    .setDuration(1000) -> ms
    .setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
```

Be sure to check the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) for all available methods.

Comment: This answer is not about the shortest path implementation

Comment: @Rustam Samandarov why not? The method rotationBy() forces minimal rotation. The ViewProperty part is just sugar.

Comment: I'm talking about -2 + 1 degrees received from device sensor ?

Comment: Ok. The problem was not with the method rotationBy but the device sensor values being received. I think we must apply high pass filter

Comment: What are you talking about? Theres nothing in the question about what you are suggesting. Am I not seeing something?